# How can i loop in a subfolder with Jekyll

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I'm currently using jekyll and i have a folder named "articles" which is located in the root of my project.

Inside this folder i have 2 subfolder named "fr" and "eng".

My goal is to loop inside the "fr" folder in one page and in the "eng" one with another page.

I have tried to use `{% for this in site.articles.fr %}` but i did not work.

I also tried `{% assign folder1 = site.articles | where_exp: "this" , "this.path contains 'folder1'"%}
{% for this in folder1 %}` but it did not work either.

Is there another way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rename 'articles' to '_posts' to follow Jekyll standards.

The folders in the '_posts' can then be filtered like this:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.path contains '/fr/' %}
    ..your code
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```